# authorization using microsoft grahp api group info

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am trying to achieve authorization by receive group info from Microsoft Graph API.

( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

So, basically, in asp.net MVC Web API Controller Project, I have products controller, it will return below data to angular client and it will be display in drop down

```
[
{id: "864", text: "Sports", name: "145028", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "593", text: "Beauty", name: "111111", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "616", text: "Home", name: "33000D", type: null, description: ""},
]
```

now, I want to hide this product information based on user group assign, for example, if user have below group assign then only sports item should be visible.
"`id": "864-Sport",`

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
      "id": "864-Sport",
      "createdDateTime": null,
      "description": "All users at the company",
      "displayName": "All Users",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mailEnabled": false,
      "securityEnabled": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve this I'm planning to do below things.

[image]

Que#1 : Now I am not sure the yellow box as highlighted, how can I use my group info object across to all controllers( around 25) I have? in considering restful API guideline.

Que#2 : Or how do you achieve this in better way? if my approach is wrong?, I'm planning to do on server side because in future if we have one more client (let's say mobile app ) it will support this.

Que3 : Is it good idea to get token also in server side, instead of client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the yellow box as highlighted. But if you need to do authorization based on group, you can take advantage of `groupMembershipClaims`. You won't need to call Microsoft Graph API to get group info. After you modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest, the token will contain the Ids of the groups, then you could implement your authorization logic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517463/checking-azure-active-directory-group-membership-via-msal-in-a-spa-web-apis/58533354#58533354.

Comment: well, i must use micrsoft graph api because "memberof" call from there we will set group information

Answer (score 0):

**Que#1 : Now I am not sure the yellow box as highlighted, how can I use my group info object across to all controllers( around 25) I have? in considering restful API guideline.**

Answer: As there is an angular frontend, so you can save it in session. Session is used to save data in one session between client and server. If the client start a new session(restart the browser), a new session will be started and you will call the Graph API to get all groups again.

You can also use cookie or redis cache, which may still be available if client starts new session.

**Que#2 : Or how do you achieve this in better way? if my approach is wrong?, I'm planning to do on server side because in future if we have one more client (let's say mobile app ) it will support this.**

Answer: I think your approach is good.

**Que3 : Is it good idea to get token also in server side, instead of client?**

Answer: Yes, it is. The client just gets a token (called as token A) for accessing your web API. Then server get another token (called as token B) for the client.

Token A has limited permission to only your web API. In this scenario, client will not directly get a token for accessing target API (Graph API and so on). Business logic is designed in your web API. So, this prevents clients from misusing tokens (token B) to perform disallowed operations.

It is called as [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). And there is a official sample for your better understanding: [ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof)