# How to use MSAL Python library to get user roles for an Azure registered application

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

guys. I am trying to use MSAL python library to get user roles for an application I already regigered in Azure Active Directory. Please give me enlight me how to get it done in Python code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517463/checking-azure-active-directory-group-membership-via-msal-in-a-spa-web-apis) and eventually I foud roles in the id token claims. All I need to do is that I must incloude Groups claim in the token, by changing the application manifest.