# Can't get on-premise SIDs to be returned with my Azure Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I've spent quite a bit of time on this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I've read numerous articles on how to return the on-premise sids but just can't get it to work.

These are some of the articles I've read (not all!):

[Tutorial: Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a JavaScript single-page app (SPA) using auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims)

[Getting Authentication Access Tokens for Microsoft APIs](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/microsoft-apis-authentication-tokens/)

[Checking Azure Active Directory group membership via MSAL in a SPA + Web APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517463/checking-azure-active-directory-group-membership-via-msal-in-a-spa-web-apis#:%7E:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20modify%20the%20%22groupMembershipClaims%22%20field,to%20like%20below%20%3A%20%7B%20%22groups%22%3A%20%5B%221ce9c55a-9826-4e32-871c-a8488144bb32%22%5D%20%7D)

I've created my app registration in Azure AD and I know it's working as expected as the token returned contains:

```
{
  ...
  "app_displayname": "My app", 
  "appid": "1234",
  "family_name": "Joe",
  "given_name": "Soap",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "123.456.789.101",
  "name": "Joe Soap",
  ...
}
```

and all the information is correct but it just doesn't contain any "groups" claims as stated in some of these articles. I've checked Azure AD and I'm part of 28 groups. Some are 'Microsoft 365', some are 'Security Group' and some are mail related/distribution groups, so definitely not over the 500 where I've read it will return nothing and I should use another approach.

In the Manifest section, this is what I have:

```
...
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
...
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "groups",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": [
                "on_premise_security_identifier"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [
        {
            "name": "groups",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": [
                "on_premise_security_identifier"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "saml2Token": [
        {
            "name": "groups",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": [
                "on_premise_security_identifier"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

In terms of scopes, I've added the following:

```
'profile'
'User.Read'
'openid'
```

I've also tried adding the groups.readall

but to no avail. Still no groups claims returned or any other entries that look like it might be a list of SIDs.

Anyone has any ideas what I'm doing wrong? If I've left anything out, apologies and just ask away and I'll update my answer.

One last point. When I cleared my cache altogether, I get prompted with the Microsoft Sign-In but somehow, when I try to use my business (office 365) account, it won't let me log in but if I use my personal account, it does but the app registration used including the TenantId, ClientID, scopes, etc... are all from my Azure business account.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get group claims in Azure AD token?

Comment: Correct and I want the "groups" claim to only include (for now anyway) my on-premise SIDS which are believe are described as "Security Group" in Azure AD. Certainly seems that way when I check my groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: To get group claims in the access token, you must generate access token for your app or API not Microsoft Graph API. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims#configure-directory-extension-optional-claims)

My Azure AD application **manifest** looks like below:

[image]
[image]

***By doing the below the onprem SIDs will be displayed in your case.***

I exposed an API and added a scope:

[image]

Granted Admin consent to the scope:

[image]

Generated access token by passing **scope** as **`api://ClientID/group.read`** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://ClientID/group.read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, **group claims are displayed successfully**:

[image]

I generated access token by passing **same scope as you**:

```json
scope: profile user.read openid
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, ***group claims are not displayed as the access token is generated for other resource that is Microsoft Graph***.

[image]

Comment: First, thanks so much for providing such a detailed answer. I'm still going through it. I've started making the changes you suggested from https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID to https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token. Any reason why? Also, now I'm getting the following error:

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-f302-4424-xxxx-xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:62353' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You can generate the access token the same way you were generating it, But just change the scope as `api://clientID/scopename` instead of `profile user.read openid`

Comment: For sample I just generated the access token by using those endpoints

Comment: Fantastic, it worked!! Any ideas why it won't work if I include 'user.read api://..." as a scope? It works if I use the "api:// and profile". Just not with "user.read". Not that I need that scope. I'm just curious :)

Comment: That is because u have to pass api as the first scope. And AAD doesn't generate tokens for two resources at once. Pass api in the first place then it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255635/discussion-between-rukmini-and-thierry).